# Can not install osmosis package with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, mean-stack, node-modules

I am trying to install **osmosis**

[image]

Can anyone help me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Is python installed ?

Comment: python is compulsory for this? I can install other packages.

Comment: it seems to. I suggested you other package

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use cheerio if you want to do webscraping over nodejs and xml parsing. It implement every jquery method and is quite simple to use.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Comment: this is not the solution.

Comment: why not ? Do you really need to use osmosis ?

Comment: osmosis is working in my mate's system, i can not change all code to show the scrap data, its almost done, I am not able to install it in mine.

Comment: i see. Try to install Python, and tell me if problem occur again

Comment: i am using **npm install --global --production windows-build-tools** to install the python, am i correct, also i couldn't find where it has installed it.

Comment: i don't know this module, ii think you have to install it from Python website https://www.python.org/